# como hago para insertar otra fila en DGV en C# ? hago la busqueda de un producto con textbox al dar enter

Tags: c#

tengo un datagridview y un textbox en el cual hago una busqueda de un producto y al dar enter se agrega al datagridview, pero al poner otro codigo y dar enter en el textbox no se agrega en el datagridview como una segunda fila, siempre se muestra en la 1er.

talves me guian, para que se valla agregando en el datagridview.
gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
**CAPA PRESENTACION CON EL FORMULARIO**
   
private void txtbuscarProductoVenta_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
   {
       dataGridView1.DataSource = 
       xDetalleVentaModel.cdo_BuscarProductoVenta(txtbuscarProductoVenta.Text);
   }
  
 }
```

---

```
 **CAPA DATOS**
        /********************************************
                 METODO BUSCAR PRODUCTOS POR CODIGO DE BARRA
                ********************************************/
                public DataTable cd_BuscarProductoVenta(string codigobarra)
                {
                    using (var connection = GetConnection())
                    {
                        SqlDataReader xReader;
                        DataTable xDataTable = new DataTable();
        
                        connection.Open();
        
                        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            command.Connection = connection;
                            command.CommandText = "select codigoBarra AS CODIGO, " +
                   
    
                                "nombProducto AS PRODUCTO, " +
                                           "pv AS 'PVenta' " +
                                           "FROM tproducto " +
                                           "where codigoBarra=@cbarra ";
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbarra", codigobarra);
                        xReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        xDataTable.Load(xReader);
    
                        return xDataTable;
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

```
    **CAPA MODEL**
        
 private string codigoBarra;
 private string nombProducto;
 private int estadoProducto;
 private int idMarca;
 private int idCategoria;
 private int idUnidadMedida;
 private decimal pc;
private decimal pv;
 private decimal dto;
 private int stockActual;
 private int stockMinimo;
 private string desProducto;
 private string rutaimg;
    
 public DetalleVentaModel(string codigoBarra, string nombProducto, int estadoProducto, int idMarca, int idCategoria, int idUnidadMedida, decimal pc, decimal pv, decimal dto, int stockActual, int stockMinimo, string desProducto, string rutaimg)
            {
                this.codigoBarra = codigoBarra;
                this.nombProducto = nombProducto;
                this.estadoProducto = estadoProducto;
                this.idMarca = idMarca;
                this.idCategoria = idCategoria;
                this.idUnidadMedida = idUnidadMedida;
                this.pc = pc;
                this.pv = pv;
                this.dto = dto;
                this.stockActual = stockActual;
                this.stockMinimo = stockMinimo;
                this.desProducto = desProducto;
                this.rutaimg = rutaimg;
            }
    
            public DetalleVentaModel()
            { 
            }
           
            /********************************************
              MEDTODO BUSCAR PRODUCTOS POR CODIGO DE BARRA
             ********************************************/
            public DataTable cdo_BuscarProductoVenta(string cb)
            {
                DataTable xDataTable = new DataTable();
                xDataTable = xDetalleVentaDatos.cd_BuscarProductoVenta(cb);
                return xDataTable;
            }
```

Buenas noches, tengo un datagridview y un textbox en el cual hago una busqueda de un producto y al dar enter se agrega al datagridview, pero al poner otro codigo y dar enter en el textbox no se agrega en el datagridview como una segunda fila, siempre se muestra en la 1er.

Answer (score 0):

logre mi objetivo pero con un PERO, el contenido que estoy trayendo lo guardo en una variable aquí esta el PERO , estoy usando 2 datagrid uno para obtener el DATO y el otro donde estoy agregando la información y cuando hago otra búsqueda, en el 2do datagrid se agrega ese producto en la siguiente fila.

no quiero ocupar 2 datagridview, tiene que ser uno, y lo que quiero hacer es lo que les explico al inicio. les dejo la informacion por si alguien busca como pasar de un datagrid a otro.

sequire probando.

```
 private void txtbuscarProductoVenta_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
             dataGridView2.DataSource = xDetalleVentaModel.cdo_BuscarProductoVenta(txtbuscarProductoVenta.Text);

             int codigoBarra= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells["codigoBarra"].Value.ToString());

             dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { codigoBarra });
             txtbuscarProductoVenta.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**

### MEDIO-SOLUCION 2

**

para que no se pierdan en lo que hice, cuando se agregra el codigo en el texto y al darle enter el se inserta en el datagridview como se muestra en la imagen.

hice un metodo bool de verificacion si existe el producto en la BD, mientras se lean las filas y exista agregame el dato la informacion encontrada en las varialbes prodcache.codbarra=reader.getstring(0);

para guardarla en la variable y mostrarla o volver a capturar ese valor en la capa de presentacion hice otra clase llamada prodcache es publica y estatica
en la cual solo se puede acceder a los campos mientras el programa este abierto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
/*VERIFICAR SI EL USUARIO EXISTE EN LA BD*/
        public bool pcd(string cb)
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "select codigoBarra,nombProducto,pv " +
                                       "FROM tproducto " +
                                       "where codigoBarra=@cb ";
                    
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb", cb);
                    
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                       prodcache.codbarra = reader.GetString(0);
                       prodcache.nombprod = reader.GetString(1);
                       prodcache.pv = reader.GetDecimal(2);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

como lo mencione en la capa presentacion en el formulario principal tengo un textbox el cual agrego un codigo de producto le doy enter verifica si existe y si es asi lo agrega al datagridview, en el codigo les muestro donde hago la captura

```
private void txtbuscarProductoVenta_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
           
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        
        var verificar = xDetalleVentaModel.cdo_pcd(txtbuscarProductoVenta.Text);
        if (verificar != true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El producto con este Codigo no Existe");
           
        }
        else
        {
            string codbarra = prodcache.codbarra;
```

AQUI CREO LAS VARIABLES CON EL MISMO VALOR QUE TIENEN EN LA BD
Y DE ESTA MANERA AGO LA CAPTURA, COMO ESTAN EN CACHE  Y CON LA CLASE prodcache.nombprod;

```
  string nombprod = prodcache.nombprod;
        int cantidad = 0;
        decimal pv=prodcache.pv;
        decimal dto = 0;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { nombprod, cantidad,Convert.ToDecimal(pv),dto });
    }
   
    txtbuscarProductoVenta.Text = "";

}
```

esto parece un monologo,
esta correcto como lo tengo?
se puede mejorar?

Comment: Encontre la menera de hacerlo. Estare publicando de la manera q lo ise, mas tarde les tiro la respuesta saludos, solo les pido que si ay una manera mejor de acerlo o si puedo mejorar lo que tengo hagalon saber.